# Communication between angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a 'master' which uses `templateUrl` to specify which markup it should use.  Within that template, I use 'rows' directive to layout `div`'s in a view. Thus, the 'master' directive is a sort of parent to the 'rows'.

The 'rows' directive also uses `templateUrl`. The 'master' and 'rows' directives are re-used in many cases but I need to have the 'rows' directive layout its rows differently in each one. This prevents me from using attributes on the 'rows' directive since that would have a global affect.

I would like to add attributes on the 'master' directive and have those somehow pass-through to the 'rows' directive.

Is there a way I can accomplish this? I've seen an EggHead tutorial on inter-directive communication but that uses the 'child' directive as an attribute on the 'parent', which won't work for me.

I also read that I could use a service to communicate between the two but I'm unclear on how to do that. Angular's `$broadcast` might work, but given the number of rows, there could be a lot of that and if it's not serially done, my layout may suffer.

Comment: Post something on jsFiddle, but off the top of my head use scope: '@' on bothe the sub directive definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some would argue that you should use events but I think in your case directive level controllers to store data would be better. Since your **row** directive is dependent on your **master** directive you can use that to your advantage and store shared information in the **master** directive.

```
module.directive('masterDir', function() {
    return {
        // Requiring yourself makes 
        //   the directive level controller
        //   available in the link function
        require: 'masterDir',
        controller: function($scope) {
            // The return is needed to support Angular 1.2
            return this;
        },
        link: {
            pre: function(scope, element, attrs, masterDirCtrl) {
                masterDirCrtl.someAttribute = attrs.someAttributeFromTheDom;
            },
            post: function() {
            }
        }
    }
});


module.directive('rowDir', function() {
    return {
        require: 'masterDir',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, masterDirCtrl) {
            var parentDirectiveAttr = masterDirCrtl.someAttribute;
        }
    }
});
```